# On what conditions are there different versions of dependency in compile scope on Maven Dependency Analyzer?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

[image]

[image]

as shown above, for the same xx-client dependency, there are two different versions in compile scope, 2.0.1 and 2.0.3, how is it possible? does this mean classes from these two versions of dependencies will co-exist in the jvm instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word *omitted* means *left out*. The report is saying that Maven *did not* include the 2.0.1 dependency that the `-core` and `-logger` asked for because something else asked for a newer 2.0.3, and Maven selected that one.